# Violating 1st normal form, is it okay for my purpose?

Tags: database, arrays, serialization, normalization

So I'm making a running log, and I have the workouts stored as entries in a table.  For each workout, the user can add intervals (which consist of a time and a distance), so I have an array like this:

```
[workout] =>
    [description] =>
    [comments] =>
    ...
    [intervals] =>
        [0] =>
            [distance] => 200m
            [time] => 32
        [1] =>
            [distance] => 400m
            [time] => 65
        ...
```

I'm really tempted to throw the "intervals" array into serialize() or json_encode() and put it in an "intervals" field in my table, however this violates the principles of good database design (which, incidentally, I know hardly anything about).

Is there any disadvantage to doing this?  I never plan on querying my table based on the contents of "intervals".  Creating a separate table just for intervals seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity, so if anyone with more experience has had a situation like this, what route did you take and how did it work out?

Comment: By the way what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm using CodeIgniter's active records class for interacting with the data but MySQL is the RDBMS.

Comment: Just reading the [atomicity section here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity). I guess in the end it all comes down to an equation involving these variables (a) probability that you might want to decompose it in the future (b) benefit of not doing so now (c) likely hassle of changing your mind later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bad idea. For example, how large should the intervals field be? If you break this into two tables, since it looks like a one-to-many relationship, you will not need to consider an artifical size constraint on the number of intervals.

Also, although you are saying you will never need to query based on the intervals, you may later change your mind and find cases where you actually do want to do that. Why limit your abilities and artificially denormalize this particular case. The creation of two tables is not all that complex. Also, you can always join them in a view to treat them as a single logical data set for queries and have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Michael Goldshetyn: I'm imagining "intervals" as a CLOB if it's hung off of workouts, so for all practical intents the size is unlimited, what are you thinking?

Comment: Yes, really it would better be described as user data in a black box.  It won't be processed or analyzed, just stored and retrieved when the user wants to look at it.  The only thing I was wondering is since the nature of the data is a type of array, there would be some disadvantage to storing it as just a string (performance, etc.)

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me.  I think I'm going to create a separate table now in case I need to use the values in the future.  It does break my nice little database set-up I had going though... (one table for users, one for workouts, one for sessions -- now I have one called workout-intervals haha)

Comment: @Michael Goldshetyn: Okay, now I have a follow-up question.  For this second table "intervals", I'm giving it fields: workout_id, distance, and time.  However, since a user can add multiple intervals, it is possible that two rows in this table could be identical, which also violates 1NF.  Do I just give each row an interval id?  That seems sort of pointless...

Comment: @Nick: instead of giving interval it's own ID, add a column I'll call "cardinality" that indicates what order the interval took place relative to others in the workout. Then make a unique constraint across all columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you never plan on having to decompose the data you are storing to search against it or to read/update/delete/insert individual values I would just chuck it in and treat it as a single atomic entity for your purposes.

Strings can be decomposed into individual characters but no one claims they violate 1NF AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

That the values are numeric suggests to me that you'll eventually find a need to perform some sort of mathematical function against them such as an average or standard deviation. As such you'd be better off storing them in such a way that you can use SQL to manipulate them as opposed to pulling it back into a programming language.

Now, that doesn't necessarily mean you have to use another table. But it's certainly the easiest, standardized way of doing so. But if you really want to store it away with your other data in one table (i.e. the `workout` table), use XML.

I say XML because most database engines offer non standard SQL for querying those values out. SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL all have ways of doing so. Serialization binds you to whatever programming language you're working with (e.g. Java). JSON doesn't have SQL support AFAIK so you still need to pull it back into a programming language to manipulate in a meaningful fashion.

Comment: +1 I guess a need for statistical analysis could indeed be quite likely.

Comment: You know, I wasn't considering doing anything statistical with the data, but supposing I decided to in the future, I suppose there is a trade-off between the amount of work I'd be doing now, and the amount I'd be doing later..